# Don't work response Disposition attachfile xlsx file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working on trying to use Apache POI to make an xlsx file.
However, it is not working. Please help me.

I want an xlsx file download but that is not working. Send url ajax and a success alert is shown, but file is not downloaded.

There is no error output to the console. It just is not working.

```
private void makeExcel(List<Map<String, Object>> list, ArrayList<String> columnTitle,String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
    
    ArrayList<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        Map<String, Object> m = list.get(0);
        for (String key : m.keySet()) {
            columnList.add(key);
        }
    }

    //  1. Workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    //  2. Sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");

    XSSFSheet sheet2 = workbook.createSheet("sheet2");

    //  3. Row
    XSSFRow row = null;
    
    XSSFRow row2 = null;

    //  4. Cell
    XSSFCell cell = null;
    
    XSSFCell cell2 = null;
    
    CellStyle headStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

    headStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColorPredefined.YELLOW.getIndex());
    headStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    headStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        int i = 0;

        for (Map<String, Object> mapObject: list) {
            row = sheet.createRow((short)i);
            if(i == 0) {
            if(columnTitle !=null &&columnTitle.size() >0){
                for(int j=0; j<columnTitle.size(); j++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short)j);
                    cell.setCellStyle(headStyle);
                    cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(columnTitle.get(j)));

                }
                i++;
                row=sheet.createRow((short)i);
                }
            }
            if (columnList != null && columnList.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < columnList.size() ; j ++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short)j);
                    cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(mapObject.get(columnList.get(j))));
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
//  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
//      fileName =  URLEncoder.encode(fileName,"UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+","%20");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=excelFileName.xlsx");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
          
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        workbook.write(out);
//      out.flush();
    
        out.close(); 
        workbook.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details about what you want to achieve, what you have tried and what exactly is not working. It is very unlikely that somebody can help you if you just post a wall of code and "it does not work".

Comment: i want xlsx file download but that is not working
send url ajax and success alert show but file is not download

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem
response don't work because ajax.
send url use href it's work